Can't open file app. Kubernetes and Docker
im getting the error: python: can't open file '/home/validator_scheduler/validator_rq_scheduler.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
when I try to create a deployment, i want the python file to be loaded from the volume and the volume to be available for updates via version control/ manual changes etc...
I have included the folder structure, deployment and PVC manifests.
I suspect it might have something to do with the persistent volumes or the way I have written my paths.
I'll appreciate any help. Thanks in advance guys.
Docker File :

    FROM python
    
    WORKDIR /home/validator_scheduler
    
    COPY requirements.txt .
    
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y dnsutils
    
    RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
    
    COPY . /home/validator_scheduler
    
    CMD ["python" , "validator_rq_scheduler.py"]

Folder structure
monitoring-system
  validator_scheduler
    validator_rq_scheduler.py

manifest:
DEPLOYMENT
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: validator-rq-scheduler-deployment
  labels:
    app: validator-rq-scheduler
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: validator-rq-scheduler
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: validator-rq-scheduler
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: validator-rq-scheduler
          image: BLABLACOMPANY/monitoring-system:validator-rq-scheduler
          workingDir: /home/validator_scheduler
          volumeMounts:
            - name: validator-scheduler
              mountPath: /home/validator_scheduler
          env:
            - name: REDIS_URL
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: app-secrets
                  key: REDIS_URL
      volumes:
        - name: validator-scheduler
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: validator-scheduler-pvc
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: docker-registry-secret


PVC
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: validator-scheduler-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi


Where did you place your Dockerfile. Can you confirm if you have it inside monitoring-system directory?

The Docker-file is downloaded from a remote image ( didnt work locally as well ), its placed inside of the validator_scheduler directory

Where exactly does the volume come in?  The volume mount will hide everything in the image.  Volumes and especially Kubernetes PVCs are for storing data, not the application code; you should be able to delete the volume and run the unmodified image.

Once i set the volume to be the same directory, it overridden the container content failing the pod.
I used initContainers to fix it and mount it so the volume is not empty during init.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
